# Fit generalized linear mixed model (with lme4 or other) to cumulative data of a continuous variable

Tags: lme4-nlme, glmm, fitting, cumulative-distribution-function

I have measurements of resin production of pine, which are taking tapping the tree, that is, making a physical wound and collecting the resin in a pot. When the pot is full we replace it with an empty one and we weigh the produced resin. As the rate of resin production decreases with time after wounding, the period among measurements is increasingly longer.
I would like to model resin production as a function of time from wounding (and treatments, which correspond to different tapping methods) in a generalized linear mixed models framework (better with lme4 in R), but I realize I have really estimates of the cumulative distribution of resin production but not good estimates of daily resin production.
Is there a way to model that in an glmm framework?
I've been looking to several distribution functions, but none of them seem to approach the general shape of a cumulative function. I really would need, for example to fit the model to the CDF of a Gaussian or Gamma distribution, instead of fitting the model to the PDF of a Gaussian or Gamma distribution. Can that be acomplished in any way? Or am I wrong in trying to do that?
Thanks!!
Asier